# Let browser save username/password values in a login <form>?

Tags: gwt

I have a GWT app, and need a user login form. I want to let the browser save the username and password for the user. I believe I need to use a 'regular' form for this (not one generated by GWT). So I made a simple form:

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Now I'd like to interrupt the submission process, grab the username/password, do login via RPC, but have the browser save the contents of those fields for the user, if they want. There are a few posts on the GWT dev boards about it, not sure which one works because none of them are working out of the box for me. I think it should look like:

```
FormPanel form = FormPanel.wrap(Document.get().getElementById("myform"), false);
form.setAction("javascript:;");
form.addSubmitHandler(new SubmitHandler() {
    public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event) {
        // Do my RPC call here?
        // User should have been prompted to save password already now?
    }
});
```

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 12):

This depends on how your form (`myform`) looks because every browser uses its own heuristic to discover a potential login form with credentials to store (Chrome for example needs an action attribute present in the markup http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=29513). So what we did is to google for remember credentials feature for every browser our app must support. The result was the following form element:

```
<form id="login-form" style="display:none" action="login">
    <input type="text" tabindex="0" name="username" id="login-username">
    <input type="password" tabindex="0" name="password" id="login-password">
    <input style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;" type="submit">
</form>
```

May work for you as well.

**EDIT**

Here an example that works for me (only tried FF version 14.x). Don't forget to remove the `display:none` from the form tag.

```
public class Starter implements EntryPoint {

    private static final String FORM_ID = "login-form";
    private static final String USER_ID = "login-username";
    private static final String PASSWORD_ID = "login-password";

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        injectLoginFunction();
        TextBox fUsername = TextBox.wrap(DOM.getElementById(USER_ID));
        fUsername.setStyleName("gwt-TextBox");
        PasswordTextBox fPassword = PasswordTextBox.wrap(DOM.getElementById(PASSWORD_ID));
        fPassword.setStyleName("gwt-PasswordTextBox");
        FormPanel fLoginForm = FormPanel.wrap(DOM.getElementById(FORM_ID), false);
        fLoginForm.setAction("");
        fLoginForm.addSubmitHandler(new SubmitHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event) {
                Window.alert("test");
            }
        });
        fLoginForm.getElement().setAttribute("onsubmit", "login();return false;");
    }

    private static void doLogin() {
        Window.alert("test");
    }

    private static native void injectLoginFunction() /*-{
        $wnd.login = function() {
            @test.client.Starter::doLogin()();
        };
    }-*/;
}
```

Comment: action="login" means, the user will be redirected to http://localhost:7080/coregui/login?username=xy&password=yx, I don't want to add another servlet to handle this.

Comment: You can later modify the action attribute to what you want, important for the browsers is only what is in the DOM when the page is loaded.

Comment: And what do you have there in particular? Do you have any example of a working piece of code? I've tried "javascript:window.doSubmitForm();" where doSubmitForm is my Java function available via JSNI which do the login logic, it works, but the browser don't offer the saving the password

Comment: I added an example to my answer.

Comment: @z00bs I get alsoe redirected to  xxx?username=test&password=test. How do i prevent redirecting

Comment: @kozla13: Looks like the `onsubmit=login();return false;` is not properly set. What browser are you testing on?

Comment: @z00bs i am tesging on firefox and chrome

Answer (score 5):

While searching for the same I stumbled across this paragraph in the wiki of google-web-toolkit-incubator:

> **auto-complete and GWT**
>
> Certain browsers offer the option to store username/password combinations so that they are automatically filled in for the user the next time they visit the page. However, usually this works only if there are two input boxes (one of type password), and only if those input boxes are loaded along with the main page, and not added later via javascript (which is what GWT does).
>
> In order to force these input boxes to show up, stuff them in the project's HTML in an invisible div. Then, in GWT, instead of creating a TextBox and a PasswordTextBox, make the div visible and read out the values using the DOM. library.

see: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/LoginSecurityFAQ

Comment: both FF and Chrome. The problem is that I use my own authentication method written in Java so I have to invoke this method after clicking on submit button. 
I've tried many approaches:
 I don't want to use the "ugly" plain html login form so I used the GWT one, and after clicking on login I copy the username and password to the html hidden form and artificially click the submit button on that form. This form then runs the Java login method via JSNI -> din't work (broswer didn't suggest the password saving)

Comment: The question is what to put into the form action or onSubmit event or submit onClick event. Now I have there "javascript:window.doSubmitForm();" where doSubmitForm() is via JSNI exported javascript function and performs the login in java

Comment: Here is my html form element:

<form style="display: none;" id="login-form" method="POST" action="javascript:window.doSubmitForm();">
  Username: <input id="uname" type="text" name="username" size="5" /><br />
  Password: <input id="pword" type="password" name="passwort" size="5" /><br />
    <p><input type="submit" value="Login" /></p>
</form>

Comment: In Java I have the onClick handler on my GWT login button with following:

                       DOM.getElementById("login-username").setInnerText(user.getValueAsString());
                        DOM.getElementById("login-password").setInnerText(password.getValueAsString());
                        FormElement.as((Element) DOM.getElementById("login-form")).submit();