# remember me option for browser?

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, browser

I want to use remember me option in my website using gwt(google web toolkit) . I want when user fill id and password and click on login than browser option(popup) open like remember password or not now.

Comment: Is the question about popup or remeber me checkbox ??

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778350/let-browser-save-username-password-values-in-a-login-form

Answer (score 2):

Add  the attribute `AutoComplete` to your input fields

```
usernamebox.getElement().setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");

passwordbox.getElement().setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
```

Comment: You are using gwt rpc or form.Submit ??

Comment: In order to get that functionality work you have to submit the form ,AJAX (rpc)  won't recognize that .

Comment: i am using gwt rpc. i have a panel (textbox abd passwordtextbox)..is it posssible with rpc or not??

Comment: OK .You can use Form panel (panel.Submit()  later )in that case .With normal RPC you won't achieve that .